# Is there a way to create a bootable image of a running Ubuntu system that excludes certain paths?

Tags: backup, disk-image

I have an Ubuntu 20.04 system that I use as my media server, and I'd like to create an image of the OS (so all my programs and configuration will be preserved) without including my media in the image, and without needing to shutdown the system. I.e. I have media partitions mounted to `/drives/*` which are then combined with [mergerfs](https://github.com/trapexit/mergerfs) to provide a merged fs mounted at `/media`, so I don't want any data from `/drives` or `/media` included in the system image. I'd also like the system image to be created while the system in running, so I can have a cronjob that creates a weekly backup (which I then plan to upload to the cloud using [duplicacy](https://github.com/gilbertchen/duplicacy)). Is such a setup possible? Are there alternative solutions?

My main goal is to ensure that all my programs and their configs can be restored in case of a catastrophic failure/migrating to a new PC, so it doesn't necessarily have to be a system image as long as it satisfies that criteria (media doesn't need to be included because I back that up separately). Would it be sufficient to just use duplicacy to backup all files on the fs (so everything in `/` other than `/drives` and `/media`), or would restoring files that way not work as intended?

Answer (score 0):

Your distribution already does almost all of what you want and describe, the system files are backed up somewhere on their servers. You can get those files anytime, what you need is to backup your configuration changes, the listing of packages you normally install perhaps in a script for quick re-install. The script could even copy the tiny little text files that are configs for your apps back into place or use the idea below to do it in the cloud. Then it is matter of your media which you already backup, putting it into place. That seems to cover what you need done, unless you think your cloud provider can get your binaries back onto your computer faster than your distro's servers can. In short backing up, already duplicated many times in the cloud, by your distribution makes little to no sense to me. As does that cloud term they are servers just like any other machine out there, doing what they have been from the beginning.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/etckeeper

Comment: I see your point, my only question then is which folders would I need to backup manually then? I know lots of stuff is saved in  /etc/, but according to `sudo ncdu /` and some exploring, I have lots of data in /var/ as well, and my fear is missing something (the goal here is to be able to grab everything in one go). Hence why I figured if possible just make my own system image, as I've only used like 30gb outside of my media

Comment: The `/var` is for logs and other variable data it is of no importance to the running of the system except being there for that purpose as a directory. What needs to be backed up are the manually edited by you files in the `/etc` directory. Those are your personal configuration changes to the system files, if you made none then it does not need backed up as it has the defaults in place for everything. And your `/home/username` directory this has all your user configuration details, your app preferences, your videos stored in those directories, music, email, browser history....

Comment: Oh if you have web or other servers with data created by you there then those files need to be backed up as well.